# PHP filter_var function output

Tags: php, filter

I want to understand PHP filter_var function. I have the following code, but it does not print something in the screen. Why? Should't it print 'Hi'?

```
$string = "Hi";
$ad =filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^T(.*)/"))); //begins with T

if ($ad === false)
    echo hi;
```

Comment: there is an error **Notice: Use of undefined constant hi - assumed 'hi'**

echo hi; > **echo 'hi';**

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @dan08 you are right.. you beat me to it.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "Hi";` instead?

Comment: Also, if you want to do this, much less confusing to just say `if (strpos($string, "T") !== 0) {echo "Hi";}`

Comment: @miken32 That's find for this case, but he's trying to learn about `filter_var` in general.

Comment: @miken32 As the warning message says, it's automatically translating it to `echo "Hi";`. So that's not the problem.

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/lTvATN